# Android: Capture image using webview

Tags: android, webview, filechooser

I'm trying to access device's gallery/camera inside a webview but I'm not able to do the same. When I try it using a browser, the device opens the gallery and lets me choose an image and provides an option to capture.

I've already gone through other posts related to the issue. None of them worked for me. Is there any way I can achieve it? Please have a look at the server side code.

```html
<input id="files" type="file" name="images[]" multiple accept="image/*" capture="camera"/>
```

(used inside a Laravel blade)